# How to print current files on git index?

Tags: git

I can print the currently committed tree with:

```
git cat-file -p master^{tree}

100644 blob 8fe01e69e28f7c6997c0f5372c015363947582d8    .angular-cli.json
100644 blob 6975847ed5aa229532141a971337caca0a401451    .dockerignore
100644 blob 1f354482f8681a1b017bc4fdde17a4802e84b06a    .editorconfig
100644 blob 9c4b02c9bd7338416bcb4037c5d5fac4c116bca5    .env.example
040000 tree d9e02522647d4f28dc40f62dca564afa48fba019    .github
```

I'm now looking to know how to print files in my current index, staged files? **I'm looking for a low-level command like `git cat-file` and not for a high-level command.**

I see there is this `index` file:

```
ls .git/index 
.git/index
```

But what is the command to print its content (again low-level command, with an argument to this file)?

Comment: Could you please specify what do you mean by low-level?
You could try with git ls-files: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

Comment: Actually, this is good for my use case thanks.  (plumbing vs porcelain).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git cat-file` only prints the contents of objects (trees, blobs, etc).  If you want to display the contents of the index, you need the similarly named - but different - `git ls-files`.  Use the `--stage` command to show the stage:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 234d33c1e3554c5f3428f0d7d5c508e4cec6d148 0   README.md
100644 efdf34514e7d7f71ef1a53c441fabbcef39c7087 0   src/foo.h
100644 a2d78b7702b46a25dd1fe86ec230a7911ed18e36 0   src/foo.c
100644 7807599d8d4971566e3b92e474ee88ad9f0217aa 0   test.c
```

This shows you the contents of the index with the stage information, including the object ID, stage level and file mode.  You could also show the contents of the disk cache information instead: metadata like the timestamp and filesize, which git uses to determine if a file may have changed on disk and needs to be examined.  To view that information, then you can use the `--debug` flag:

```
$ git ls-files --debug
README.md
  ctime: 1523823765:79574029
  mtime: 1523823765:79245702
  dev: 16777221 ino: 34669602
  uid: 501      gid: 20
  size: 8253    flags: 0
src/foo.c
  ctime: 1523830223:524847547
  mtime: 1523830223:524623074
  dev: 16777221 ino: 34676974
  uid: 501      gid: 20
  size: 4071    flags: 0
src/foo.h
  ctime: 1523752084:2627730
  mtime: 1523752084:2060254
  dev: 16777221 ino: 34621108
  uid: 501      gid: 20
  size: 36809   flags: 0
tests/response.c
  ctime: 1523826062:78659995
  mtime: 1523826062:78659995
  dev: 16777221 ino: 34672776
  uid: 501      gid: 20
  size: 30615   flags: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer here is incorrect.

The `--stage` option to `git ls-files` does not mean "list only staged files"; rather, it only modifies the format of the output. From the `git ls-files` man page:

> `-s, --stage`
>
> Show staged contents' mode bits, object name and stage number in the output.

To see only files in the index, you can use:

```
$ git diff-index HEAD
```

For example, if I have a repository containing three files:

```
$ git ls-files
file1
file2
file3
```

And I add a new file:

```
$ git add file4
```

Then `git ls-files --stage` will show all the files in the repository, including the index:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 5ce91bb123e763d519b0ad929eaf56a2464c7c36 0   file1
100644 5ce91bb123e763d519b0ad929eaf56a2464c7c36 0   file2
100644 5ce91bb123e763d519b0ad929eaf56a2464c7c36 0   file3
100644 6baefff73e8fec350b060518bd108aa5d80b24ed 0   file4
```

But `git diff-index HEAD` will show only the staged files:

```
$ git diff-index HEAD
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 6baefff73e8fec350b060518bd108aa5d80b24ed A  file4
```

If you want just the file names, the `--name-only` flag will get you what you want:

```
$ git diff-index --name-only HEAD
file4
```

Comment: `ls-files --stage` doesn't show all the files "in the repository", it shows all the files _in the index_.  That's because the index contains all the files that _will be in the next commit_.  It does not contain just the _new_ or _changed_ files (which you might call "staged" files).  `diff-index` shows you the difference between the HEAD and the index, hence the name - which is a very different notion than showing you the files in the index.  If you want to show the difference between HEAD and the index, then yes, `diff-index` is what you want.  But that doesn't show you the full index.

Comment: I agree that it's not 100% clear that the OP is asking for the _full_ index, not just the diff, but I think that "what is the command to print its content (again low-level command...)" and the fact that they accepted the answer suggests that yes, it's the full index they were looking for.  Which may not be what _you're_ looking for.  But thanks for the downvote!

Answer (score 0):

You could try with git ls-files:
[git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) - 
*Show information about files in the index and the working tree*

<sub>P.S. Just moved this from the comment.</sub>